# SQL database mail configuration to use a domain account that is not the SQL Service account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-mail

We have been asked to use a domain service account for everything releated to email (smtp). I looked at the SQL Database Mail and the only option that looked like Windows Auth. is the first one:

[image]

The problem is that the account we will use will not be the SQL service account.

Is there a way to make it work with a domain service account that is not the SQL Service account ?

Comment: What happens when you configure the second option using the format **Domain\Login** on the user name?

Comment: Wow.. that was that easy :o

Comment: Cool =D I'll write a proper answer adding the TSQL alternative to complement it as it might be helpful to others.

Comment: @Ronaldo, in your answer, be sure to include the security considerations if basic authentication is used without SSL.

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks for pointing that out. Please, check if the information on that matter is accurate and enough for the sake of this post. If not, feel free to improve the answer or tell me how to do so.

Comment: @Ronaldo, looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Using Database Mail Configuration Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15#DBWizard)**

You can achieve that by selecting the **Basic authentication** option and filling the user name in the `Domain\Login` format:

[image: Configuration Wizard]

You can check the [New Account Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15#NewAccount) doc to understand each parameter of the wizard.

**[Using Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/create-a-database-mail-account?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure)**

You can also use the system stored procedure [sysmail_add_account_sp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sysmail-add-account-sp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to do that. Here I used the example from the doc and added the last three parameters that are related to your question:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp  
    @account_name = 'AdventureWorks Administrator',  
    @description = 'Mail account for administrative e-mail.',  
    @email_address = 'dba@Adventure-Works.com',  
    @display_name = 'AdventureWorks Automated Mailer',  
    @mailserver_name = 'smtp.Adventure-Works.com', 
    @username = 'Domain\Login',
    @password = 'yourPassWord',
    @enable_ssl = 1;
```

---

**Security Implication**

Notice that on both examples I'm using the SSL option because, as [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) pointed out, the use of that option

> Specifies whether Database Mail encrypts communication using Secure
> Sockets Layer

as you'll see in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sysmail-add-account-sp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments). So, if you're not using a secure connection in your environment, those credentials, along with the email content, are gonna be sent in plain text to the SMTP mail server, therefore being a security issue.